# Is there a way to change the speed of printing something to match the speed of a currently playing audio file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winsound

I am using the winsound module to play audio files from a folder, and am trying to create a transcript system for a project I am working on. But currently my process of making this is slow and is as follows:

Run code:

- speech from audio file does not match speed of `print()` function
- change the `time.sleep()` time up or down
- repeat previous steps

Is there a quicker way of creating this? Perhaps by repeatedly changing the speed of the print statement to match the speed of the audio file in real time?

I am using python 3.8 so if there are any modules that could do this that would help a lot.

Also, here is a sample of the code if it helps:

```
import winsound

print("You find the access tunnel, hidden within a natural cave a mile off the main road.")
time.sleep(2)
print(" ")
print("You don't need the keycard. The door is ajar.")
time.sleep(2)
print(" ")
print("It smells here. It smells like them. Hopefully, they've moved on. You've come so far
already. You can't turn back now.")
```

Comment: Since `print` is a function in Python 3 (not a statement), you can replace the built-in one with your own that does the timing. I believe this means that if you could determine how long the sound `winsound` is playing is going to take, you could probably do what you want. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that…

Comment: thanks, will try that

Comment: take a look on this blog: https://grubdragon.github.io/2017/09/30/python-subs-easy/